# Pierdo conexión al volver a primer plano - app android

Tags: android, ciclo-de-vida

Siendo conciso. Tengo una app, con listado de productos que obtengo a través de llamadas a una API Rest con Retrofit. Todo funciona ok.
El caso de error: tengo mi aplicación en primer plano, apago la pantalla y dejo unos minutos, al activar de nuevo la pantalla y que mi aplicación vuelva a primer plano pierdo la conexión. Cualquier acceso (llamada a la API con Retrofit) devuelve timeout sin obtener el dato, como si no tuviera conexión.
Antes de cualquier llamada, siempre compruebo que tenga conexión mediante:

```
public boolean hayConexionDatos(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
}
```

Esto me indica que si hay conexión (lo compruebo haciendo debug), pero la posterior llamada me devuelve timeout.
No ocurre siempre, pero si muy a menudo (después de detectarlo varias veces lo he ido probando muchas más veces) y sobre todo, no me ocurre con cualquier otra app instalada en mi teléfono.

Como dato por si fuera algo así. Tengo la app instalada solo a través de android studio (al elegir mi teléfono como terminal de ejecución de pruebas) no está todavía subida a google play.
No sé si esto tiene que ver (pensando que android en la versión de mi teléfono, android 9, mate los APK no instalados desde google play, aunque buscado en la ayuda propia de android y no he encontrado info que lo confirme).

No pongo más código porque no se trata de ningún error de código ni tampoco sabría qué parte incluir porque todo funciona ok en situación normal...

La duda es: por qué puedo estar perdiendo la conexión?. Tal y como apunta, android me puede estar matando la app sin saberlo??.

Gracias.

Comment: Se trata de un error por el mal uso del ciclo de vida de tu Activity. Revisa la documentación del ciclo de vida de una Activity en Android. Cuando tu Activity pasa a segundo plano, no siempre vuelve ejecutando los mismos callbacks (onCreate, onResume, etc). Debes estar haciendo algo necesario para mantener la conexión en alguno de los callback que no se llama de nuevo al restaurar la Activity.

Comment: Es importante revises el LogCat cuando sucede el timeout  que mencionas

Comment: Gracias chicos. Respecto al cilco de vida, si lo tengo todo en cuenta. En realidad no se hace nada que active o desactive la conexión ni parece ser el problema. Es extraño pero cuando comento que pierde la conexión es ya total para toda la ejecución, es decir, te puedes mover por cualquier parte, navegando por las actividades y todas la peticiones dan timeout. Es necesario matar manualmente la app y volver a arrancarla para que puede volver a funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Hola @Alberto revisa el LogCat cuando regresas de background el problema debe ser relacionado a la petición.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente te comento que el uso de la clase `NetWorkInfo` es obsoleto y debes usar  la clase ConectivityManager y metodo getNetworkCapabilities() o Clase NetworkCapabilities, este es el método correcto:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

Ahora con respecto a tu problema:

> Cualquier acceso (llamada a la API con Retrofit) devuelve timeout sin
>   obtener el dato, como si no tuviera conexión.

**Un timeout no indica que no tengas conexión, el problema es que tratas de establecer conexión pero se agota el limite de tiempo establecido.**

Si estas realizando una petición usando Retrofit lo que indicas puede suceder también en primer plano.

Por default usando `Retrofit` el `Connection timeout` y el `Read timeout` estan definidos en  10 seconds, puedes como opción aumentar el timeout de tu petición:

```
   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)      //1 minuto
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)   //1 minuto
        .build();
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys.

Efectivamente, si es un timeout, SocketTimeoutException.
Respecto a OkHttpClient ya tuve en cuenta el parámetro de Timeout y por ahí no van los tiros.

De hecho me pierde el hecho de que la app se queda así hasta que la "mates" manualmente. Una vez ocurre ya todas las peticiones que realices navengando por la app devuelven timeout. 

Como comentaba, si fuerzo detención y abro de nuevo la app vuelve a la normalidad y funciona correctamente todo el tiempo que la use.